# php Storing S_SESSIONS with same name passed through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, loops

I have jquery onclick triger that pass:

```
var product = id;
var name = name;
$.post("./shop/basket.php", {"product": product,"name": name});
```

to **basket.php** where I store:

```
$_SESSION['product'] = $_POST['product'].'-'.$_POST['name'];
```

But each time a new click is generated it rewrites the `S_SESSION` instead of adding it as new `$_SESSION`.

How to store all values in `$_SESSION['product']` so I can loop it later and extract each `$_SESSION['product']` ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: wow.. `$_SESSION['product'][] = ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['product'][]=$_POST['product'].'-'.$_POST['name']; 
//[] makes it multi-dimensional so you can hold multiple product values
```

To loop through the values use [foreach()](http://php.net/foreach):

```
foreach($_SESSION['product'] as $key=>$val){
    echo $key.' - '.$val."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I tried this before I post the question but when I loop it echo prints only 1 $_SESSION - 0 - 793-Unisex - is it possible on page refresh to loose data?

Comment: @thecore7 No, unless you have a `session_destroy()` somewhere at the end of your code. Could you paste your full code?